# Incluir parámetros en el query string de un WebRequest

Tags: c#, json

estoy consumiendo una API y me gustaria saber como podría paginar el metodo GET o añadir parametros en el WebRequest.

Actualmente, me está funcionando con pocos registros, pero temo que a la larga, tenga que paginar o usar parámetros de fecha.
Alguien me podría ayudar a completar el método para usar tanto parametro como paginar por favor?
sé que existe por ejemplo el parametro start_date y end_date a los que postman, si los informo, me devuelve el resultado correcto.

```
public static List<Orders> GetOrdersPendientes(string Key)
        {
            string url = Urls.url_Orders;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", Key);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            
            List<Orders> O = new List<Orders>();

            try
            {
                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream strReader = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        if (strReader == null) return null;
                        using (StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(strReader))
                        {
                            string responseBody = objReader.ReadToEnd();
                            JObject objeto = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
                            IList<JToken> results = objeto["orders"].Children().ToList();

                            foreach (var p in results)
                            {
                                List<OrderLine> Lineas = new List<OrderLine>();
                                Orders X = new Orders();
                                ....
                                O.Add(X);
                                
                            }
                            return O;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Gracias!

Comment: Pues, la paginación se hace del lado de la API. Tú mantienes ese código? La API soporta paginación? Cuando haces el request a través de Postman, cuál es la Url resultante? Si es un GET, has intentado incluir los parámetros en el querystring?

Comment: @Arriel gracias por tu respuesta. Si, mantengo el código. Si, la API soporta paginación. El tema del querystring tal vez es el que se me escapa. Me podrías indicar como incluir el parámetro por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes primero agrgar los parámetros en tu método, `public static List<Orders> GetOrdersPendientes(string Key, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)` te aconsejo ponerlo como *nulleable* xq a lo mejor no siempre quieres obtener los datos filtrados por rango, ahora cuando generas la Url veo que la tienes en una constante, puedes hacer algo como esto

```
var queryParams = new List<string>();
if (startDate != null)
{
    queryParams.Add($"start_date={startDate}");
} 

if (endDate!= null)
{
    queryParams.Add($"end_date={endDate}");
} 

 string url = queryParams.Any() ? 
                   $"{Urls.url_Orders}?{string.Join('&', queryParams)}" 
                   : Urls.url_Orders;
```

Ahora no se en que formato espera las fechas la api que estás consumiendo eso sería el último paso para tener todo correcto